# Where is my api url? apple quip

Tags: rest-api, oauth2

I'm trying to use the Automation API for Apple's quip server (https://quip-apple-uat.com) and I'm looking for the authorization url for OAuth.

Following code at https://github.com/quip/quip-api/blob/master/nodejs/quip.js line 89
And https://quip.com/dev/automation/documentation/current#tag/Authentication

Get 404 for https://quip-apple-uat.com/1/oauth/login

So... where is it?

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, the api sits on a subdomain "platform".  I thought I had tried that earlier, but now that I think of it, I think I was trying "production" or something.

So the answer is:

https://platform.quip-apple-uat.com